# Strange behavior in time.Parse function in Go

Tags: datetime, time, go

When you execute the following code snippet, which is derived mainly from [Go's time package documentation and its Parse function example](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse):

```
package main

import (
   "time"
   "fmt"
)

var shortForm = "2006-Jan-02"
t, _ := time.Parse(shortForm, "2013-Feb-03")
fmt.Println(t)
```

Then, you can get the correct result, `2013-02-03 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`, in your console.

However, when you change the `shortForm` value slightly, such as `2007-Jan-02`, `2006-Feb-02`, or `2006-Jan-01`, it outputs wrong results, and the output looks not even regularly, such as `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`, `2013-03-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`, or `2013-01-03 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`.

So why does the function behave such strangely? And how can I deal with it? Every time I use the function, should I always define layout variable as `2006-Jan-02`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `time.Parse` and `time.Format` functions use the numbers in the layout argument to identify which date component is referred to:

- `1`: month (alternatively can appear in words as `Jan` / `January`)
- `2`: day
- `3`: hour (alternatively as `15` for 24 hour clock)
- `4`: minute
- `5`: second
- `6`: year (alternatively as `2006` for 4 digit year)
- `7`: time zone (alternatively as `MST` for time zone code).

So when you change the layout string from `2006-Jan-02` to `2006-Jan-01`, you are saying that the month is represented in the time string twice, leading to unexpected results.

Comment: It looks like a strange way of formatting and I found it pretty tough to get what's happening internally until you helped me in your excellent clarification... So I presume this is beyond the scope of `Go` and more closely related to how computers or languages handle time in general, right? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Other languages use strings like 'MM-dd-yyyy' and then you have to remember that 'MM' is month whereas 'mm' is minutes (or is it the other way around?) and that MM means the two digit month (possibly with a leading zero) and MM means the abbreviation ("Jan" or whatever), etc. I think the Go approach is a little simpler.